# ElasticSearch won't sort

Tags: elasticsearch

My ElasticSearch query with sort doesn't sort:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "id": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Adding the "sort" doesn't have any effect except that every result now has an additional attribute

```
sort: [0]
```

It looks like the "sort" attribute is 0, therefore the order of the results doesn't change.

"id" is an actual attribute of the documents in my index. Changing it to "idFOOBAR" throws "[No mapping found for [idFOOBAR] in order to sort on]", so it seems to recognize the attribute. Also tried other attributes like "userId" etc., same outcome.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the attribute mapping from `index="no"` to `index="not_analyzed"` fixed it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you please explain how exactly you changed the attribute mapping? Is this a property of the `ElasticSearch` node?

Comment: Do you already have a mapping in place? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I created the index with: `POST <index> {"mappings": {"<type>": {"properties": {"<field>": {"type": "<type>", "index": "not_analyzed"}}}}`. Thanks anyway!