# Get sorted search result in pyes

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

Here is a minimal example.

I have an index `'test_index'` with the following records:

```
{u'name': u'b'}
{u'name': u'e'}
{u'name': u'a'}
{u'name': u'c'}
{u'name': u'd'}
```

I want to get the records in alphabetical order of the `'name'` field. I use the `sort` argument, but the result is not sorted:

```
q = pyes.query.MatchAllQuery().search()
tuple(record['name'] for record in conn.search(q, indices = 'test_index', sort = 'name'))
```

Result:

```
(u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e', u'a')
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try using sort = 'name:ASC' and sort = 'name:DESC' and tell us if there is any difference? Code looks correct imo.

Comment: Already tried it, it doesn't work. However, I just now found the solution, it was a problem with the attribute mapping - see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065667/elasticsearch-wont-sort

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Question creator found the solution and posted it in the comments:

> Already tried it, it doesn't work. However, I just now found the solution, it was a problem with the attribute mapping - see this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/18065667/elasticsearch-wont-sort

Old:
Unfortunately I couldn't test it here but try this version pls:

```
q = pyes.query.MatchAllQuery()
tuple(record['name'] for record in conn.search(q, indices = 'test_index', sort = 'name'))
```

Also note that there is now an official python api for elastic search.

http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/